# Silverlight Bing maps over SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, ssl, bing-maps

I have a silverlight 4 application which uses Bing map. Now when application runs over http everything works perfectly fine. But when we host silverlight application on SSL, bing maps stop working. Below is the code which is used of showing map.

At application start

```
Vexel.Maps.SilverlightExtension.Configuration.SynchronousConfiguration.LoadMapConfiguration();
```

File: Configuration.baselayer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <MapControl version="v1">

        <!-- MapMode Uri Format -->
        <!-- Meritech Office Bing -->
        <add key="RoadUriFormat" value="http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r{quadkey}.png?g=1&amp;mkt={Culture}&amp;shading=hill&amp;n=z"/>
        <add key="AerialUriFormat"  value="http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{quadkey}.jpeg?g=1&amp;n=z"/>
        <add key="AerialWithLabelsUriFormat" value="http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h{quadkey}.jpeg?g=1&amp;mkt={Culture}&amp;n=z"/>
        <add key="AerialLabelsUriFormat" value="http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/ho{quadkey}.jpeg?g=1&amp;mkt={Culture}&amp;n=z"/>

    </MapControl>
</configuration>
```

Now please let me know what has to be done to get map data over SSL.
Would be really thankful if anyone could help me in this.

Also i heard that for SSL silverlight application we have to host our own bing map server over SSL. Is this true?

If nothing could be done then we have to convert the complete project in asp.net/HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps Silverlight control does not support HTTPS out of the box. However, someone has figured out an interesting workaround http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43c13236-5733-4779-97c6-136a1ecabc6a/tell-bing-maps-silverlight-control-to-use-https